# Android - How to repeat icon animation in SplashScreen API

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, splash-screen, android-jetpack, android-splashscreen

I was making splash screen animation with animated-vector drawable and SplashScreen api. After a delay of 3 seconds in the ViewModel, I pass the Splash Screen, but I want the animation to repeat during these 3 seconds. I'm trying to add this logic for that but animation did not play once more. Here is MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private val splashViewModel:SplashViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        val splashScreen = installSplashScreen().apply {
            setOnExitAnimationListener { viewProvider ->
                // How can I implement repeating logic here?
                viewProvider.remove()
            }
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        splashScreen.setKeepOnScreenCondition {
            splashViewModel.isSplashShow.value
        }

        setContent {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Greeting("Android")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Here my animated vector drawable:

```
<animated-vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt">
    <aapt:attr name="android:drawable">
        <vector
            android:name="vector"
            android:width="1024dp"
            android:height="1024dp"
            android:viewportWidth="1024"
            android:viewportHeight="1024">
            <group
                android:name="group"
                android:pivotX="512"
                android:pivotY="512"
                android:scaleX="0.5"
                android:scaleY="0.5">
                <path
                    android:name="path"
                    android:pathData="M 401.1 616.7 C 401.1 652.194 412.342 686.792 433.204 715.507 C 454.067 744.222 483.498 765.604 517.254 776.573 C 551.011 787.541 587.389 787.541 621.146 776.573 C 654.902 765.604 684.333 744.222 705.196 715.507 C 726.058 686.792 737.3 652.194 737.3 616.7 C 737.3 572.134 719.577 529.348 688.065 497.835 C 656.552 466.323 613.766 448.6 569.2 448.6 C 524.634 448.6 481.848 466.323 450.335 497.835 C 418.823 529.348 401.1 572.134 401.1 616.7 Z"
                    android:fillColor="#ffb89a"
                    android:strokeWidth="1"/>
                <path
                    android:name="path_1"
                    android:pathData="M 522.7 765.1 C 410.1 765.1 318.5 673.5 318.5 560.9 C 318.5 448.3 410.1 356.7 522.7 356.7 C 562 356.7 600.2 367.9 633.2 389.1 C 665.2 409.7 690.8 438.8 707.2 473.1 C 714.3 488.1 708 506 693 513.1 C 678 520.2 660.1 513.9 653 498.9 C 641.4 474.6 623.3 454.1 600.7 439.5 C 577.5 424.5 550.5 416.6 522.7 416.6 C 443.2 416.6 378.5 481.3 378.5 560.8 C 378.5 640.3 443.2 705 522.7 705 C 542.3 705 561.3 701.2 579.1 693.6 C 594.3 687.1 612 694.2 618.4 709.5 C 624.9 724.7 617.8 742.4 602.5 748.8 C 577.3 759.6 550.4 765.1 522.7 765.1 Z"
                    android:fillColor="#33cc99"
                    android:strokeWidth="1"/>
                <path
                    android:name="path_2"
                    android:pathData="M 686.7 659.6 C 683.3 659.6 679.9 659 676.6 657.8 C 661 652.2 652.9 635 658.5 619.4 C 662.4 608.6 664.9 597.3 666.1 585.9 C 667.8 569.4 682.6 557.4 699 559.2 C 715.5 560.9 727.4 575.7 725.7 592.1 C 724 608.3 720.4 624.3 714.9 639.6 C 710.6 651.9 699.1 659.6 686.7 659.6 Z M 770 386 C 770 394.298 773.3 402.265 779.168 408.132 C 785.035 414 793.002 417.3 801.3 417.3 C 809.598 417.3 817.565 414 823.432 408.132 C 829.3 402.265 832.6 394.298 832.6 386 C 832.6 377.702 829.3 369.735 823.432 363.868 C 817.565 358 809.598 354.7 801.3 354.7 C 793.002 354.7 785.035 358 779.168 363.868 C 773.3 369.735 770 377.702 770 386 Z"
                    android:fillColor="#33cc99"
                    android:strokeWidth="1"/>
                <path
                    android:name="path_3"
                    android:pathData="M 821.1 240.6 L 760.3 240.6 L 760.3 240.2 C 758.6 240.5 756.8 240.6 755.1 240.6 C 732 240.6 713.2 216 713.2 185.6 C 713.2 182.1 713.5 178.6 713.9 175.3 L 713.9 169.4 C 713.9 129.8 681.5 97.4 641.9 97.4 L 386.3 97.4 C 346.7 97.4 314.3 129.8 314.3 169.4 L 314.3 177.4 C 314.6 180.1 314.8 182.8 314.8 185.6 C 314.8 216 292 240.6 268.9 240.6 C 268.2 240.6 267.4 240.6 266.7 240.5 L 266.7 240.6 L 254.3 240.6 L 254.3 184.8 C 254.3 168.2 240.9 154.8 224.3 154.8 C 207.7 154.8 194.3 168.2 194.3 184.8 L 194.3 241 C 122 246.5 64.6 307.3 64.6 381 L 64.6 784.2 C 64.6 861.4 127.8 924.6 205 924.6 L 821.3 924.6 C 898.5 924.6 961.7 861.4 961.7 784.2 L 961.7 381 C 961.5 303.8 898.3 240.6 821.1 240.6 Z M 901.5 784.1 C 901.5 805.4 893.1 825.6 877.8 840.8 C 862.5 856.1 842.4 864.5 821.1 864.5 L 204.9 864.5 C 183.6 864.5 163.4 856.1 148.2 840.8 C 132.9 825.5 124.5 805.4 124.5 784.1 L 124.5 381 C 124.5 359.7 132.9 339.5 148.2 324.3 C 163.5 309 183.6 300.6 204.9 300.6 C 204.9 300.6 241.9 300.9 268.8 300.6 C 295.7 300.3 330.6 280.6 330.6 280.6 C 337.8 275.1 344.4 268.5 350.1 260.9 C 365.9 240.1 374.7 213.4 374.7 185.7 C 374.7 182 374.5 178.3 374.2 174.6 L 374.2 169.5 C 374.2 163 379.7 157.5 386.2 157.5 L 641.8 157.5 C 648.3 157.5 653.8 163 653.8 169.5 L 653.8 171.8 C 653.3 176.4 653.1 181.1 653.1 185.7 C 653.1 213.4 661.8 240.2 677.7 260.9 C 684.3 269.5 691.9 276.9 700.3 282.9 C 700.3 282.9 727 300.7 760.3 300.7 L 821.1 300.7 C 842.4 300.7 862.6 309.1 877.8 324.4 C 893.1 339.7 901.5 359.8 901.5 381.1 L 901.5 784.1 Z"
                    android:fillColor="#45484c"
                    android:strokeWidth="1"/>
            </group>
        </vector>
    </aapt:attr>
    <target android:name="group">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <set>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="scaleX"
                    android:duration="700"
                    android:valueFrom="0"
                    android:valueTo="0.5"
                    android:valueType="floatType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/overshoot_interpolator"/>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="scaleY"
                    android:duration="700"
                    android:valueFrom="0"
                    android:valueTo="0.5"
                    android:valueType="floatType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/overshoot_interpolator"/>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="rotation"
                    android:startOffset="125"
                    android:duration="450"
                    android:valueFrom="0"
                    android:valueTo="360"
                    android:valueType="floatType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"/>
            </set>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
</animated-vector>
```

Comment: Okey I found a one way to achieve repeating animation but I want to control animation in MainActivity for spesific logics. But its okey. I was giving a objectAnimator to android:repeatCount="infinite", this attribute it works. If there is a way that has more control over the animation, please comment it.